# Django: authenticate the user

Tags: python, django

I have the following code:

**# creating user:**

```
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_info = forms.UserInfoForm(request.POST)
        if user_info.is_valid():
            cleaned_info = user_info.cleaned_data
            User.objects.create_user(username=cleaned_info['username'], password=cleaned_info['password'])
   render(.......)
```

This works. I can check the auth_user and I see the username and password along with all the other fields created and added.

Now, I try to authenticate the user with the following code after creating user with **username='testcase' and password='test':** using above code.

**# Authenticate User**

```
def get_entry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = authenticate(username='testcase', password='test')
        if user:
            .........
```

The user is always returned as none. What is going on? I am running django 1.10.2.

**Update:**

I can see the user created by create_user function when I log in admin. The status was not staff(as it was supposed to be). I changed that to staff to see if that was causing problem but still the get_entry method yields none for user.
It is frustrating. I don't really know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I don't. I thought create_user() method takes care of that on the background. And because I could see the user created in auth_users, It is saved. I don't know if there is anything more that .save() method does on the background.

Comment: Instead of test, try inserting the hashed password as stored in the password attribute of the auth_user table.

Comment: authenticate automatically hashes the password before it makes any comparison. I don't think hashing is needed.

Comment: Your code you have posted looks ok. What exactly do you see in the auth user table - you should see the hashed password, not the password.

Comment: I see the hashed password. That is really strange.

Comment: Try testing the `get_entry` method with a user created another way, and try logging on somewhere else (e.g. the Django admin) with a user created with the `create_user` method (you will have to set `is_staff=True`). That way you might be able to work out which of your views isn't working.

Comment: Are you using default User model? Can you please verify that you have  `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` set to `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`. This comes set by default but  good to make sure. `from django.conf import settings` then `print(settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS)`
[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends) ........

Comment: I would try manually setting the user's password in the shell just to confirm that it's being set to the value you think it is: `u = User.objects.get(username='testcase'); u.set_password('test'); u.save()`. If `get_entry` works after doing that, you know the problem is in your `create_user` view or `UserInfoForm`. I'd also throw a `print(cleaned_info)` in to ensure that your POST data is what you think it is.

Comment: @LaLZaDa : I tried that one too. Nothing changed.

Comment: @Alasdair: I changed to staff_status. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Save the user in one var, and then call user.save() because User can't call the method save() try it:

```
def create_user(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user_info = forms.UserInfoForm(request.POST)
            if user_info.is_valid():
                cleaned_info = user_info.cleaned_data
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=cleaned_info['username'], password=cleaned_info['password'])
                user.save()
       render(.......)
```

Then you need to call auth.authenticate in your function get_entry:

```
def get_entry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = auth.authenticate(username='testcase', password='test')
        if user:
            .........
```

Comment: You don't need to call `save()` after calling `create_user()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#creating-users

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct.

The problem might be in the way the params are being passed to your `create_user` view (Param passing in `get_entry` view highly unlikely to be a problem since the params `username` and `password` are hard-coded).

Try printing out `username` and `password` before passing them to `User.objects.create_user()`, since it's possible that the `password` field is not being saved properly and/or empty `password` is being passed, and Django might be creating a hash for the empty password.

P.S.: This is just a speculation, need your response over this for further diagnosis of the issue.